# How to reverse regx to not match

Tags: regex, go

I have regular which select url, I want that it not select url only word, how to not select url? instead select word like (admin,hello).

Regex

```
((.*?\w+|\W):\/\/[\w\-\.]+.*?\/*.*?\w\W+.*\/.*?\w\W+.*?\/{0,})
```

Text

```
htt$ps://b24-56kck1.$bitr%ix24.kz/com@pany/pe#rsonal/us^&er/19/k/roce/
https://1.tesssst1.ru/ororo
admin
hello
##$#$$#w_svccx354V2346Vf

    SendAjaxFilterToServer(quiz_questions);
```

Comment: Remove URLs first using `https?://\S+`, then match your "words".

Comment: Hi @Alex. Welcome to Stack Overflow. As a new contributor, I'm just reviewing your question generally to try to be helpful. Here are some suggestions. 
1. Use the abbreviation "regex" for regular expression.
2. Review your content for missing words. For example: "I have regular which" is missing "expression".

Comment: 3. Make sure your verbs match in number. "select url" is something the regex does. It is a singular regex, so the verb should be "selects". And, it is a singular URL, so it should have an "a" in front ("which selects a URL"). If you had more than one regex, you would say: "these regexs select urls". 
4. Break into sentences. 1 sentence is describing the regex you have. Next sentence should say what type of regex you want. 
5. Avoid slang like: "wanna". Use "I want"

Comment: 6. Be careful as to what "it" refers to: "I want that it not select url only word". Instead, "I want a new regex which selects a word...".
7. This should be a separate sentence "how to not select url?" Like "How do I make a regex that does not select a URL?"

Answer (score 0):

Alex, it is very hard to invert a regular expression, so you want to think in terms of the attributes of what you want to match. One thing that jumps out to me is you just want the line to contain letters. For that, you can use `^[a-zA-Z]+$`

Another way to go at it, is you can create an inverted list of characters - ones which you don't want present. This can be harder, but for the simple example input you give, you don't want ":", "/" or "#" to be in the line. That would be `^[^:/#]+$`.

These are examples of how you need to think about the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, then trip the surrounding whitespace (because of lack of support for lookaround in Go):

```
(^|[\n\s])[a-zA-Z]+([\n\s]|$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/MqyDWC/3

Comment: Go's stdlib regex library does not support lookarounds.

Comment: @Adrian - Weird. I updated the solution, but am surprised by Go's omission of the feature. :-/

Comment: They omitted lookarounds in order to handle regex as an FSM that operates in bounded time & memory. I understand the trade-off but I'm not sure I agree with it. There are third-party RE libs for Go that operate Perl-compatible I think.

Comment: @Adrian - That's very interesting. Thank you. I've actually shied away from Go because I prefer the a rich feature set in a language rather than a performance boost that comes from stripping capabilities.

Comment: The reduced feature set and performance are unrelated. The minimalist language feature set is to make learning, reading and writing Go code faster, easier, and more intuitive. Various stdlib choices may have been made for simplicity, or for performance, or both.

Comment: @Adrian - I understand the philosophy, but it's not my style. I'd personally rather have more capabilities. This regex quirk is actually a good example of why Go's "simplicity" actually makes code messier and more complicated to implement, IMO.

Comment: That's just the regex implementation in the stdlib. As I had noted earlier, there's third-party regex libraries. Go doesn't force you to use the included regex library.

Comment: @Adrian - I know, but compare that to .NET’s native Regex library which already has lookaround, named captures and pretty much all the other bells and whistles built in as part of the standard language.

Comment: It's not part of the language, it's part of the standard library. Those are two very different things. The standard library is "useful stuff people often want", but once you're importing a regex package into a project, there's no reason to choose stdlib over third-party if stdlib doesn't meet your needs. The language itself is where you get no choice; the stdlib is generally used at your option.